# If statements comparison integers

Tags: php

I have some if statements that read a variable from my mysql database and then echo out a number based on that variable.  For some reason, the code below only echos out "1"  and I dont know why.  ($x is 670, but it still echos out 1)

CODE:

```
 //connect to database and assign $x a int from database
 if ($x<=100){
 echo 1;
 }

 if ($x>=500 && $x<1000){
 echo 2;
 }

 if ($x>=1000 && $x<2500){
 echo 3;
 }

 if ($x>=2500 && $x<5000){
 echo 4;
  }

 if ($x>=5000 && $x<7500){
 echo 5;
 }

 if ($x>=7500  && $x<100000){
  echo 6;
 }

 if ($x>=10000){
 echo 7;
 }
```

EDIT: I did something stupid in my code with connecting to the DB.  Thanks for your help anyway.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried manually assign `670` to `$x` and not from database? Try it so we can figure it out.

Comment: @domanokz good call.  when i manually assign it, it works.  there must be a problem with my DB.  the variable is stored as an int

Comment: Also, try to echo the result from database.. Is it really 670?

Comment: put here `var_dump($x);`

Comment: Do use an else...if ladder if the code appears continuously. This will decrese the number of checks to be performed and increases performance. It also lets you omit one of the limits if the values are continuous.  
    `.....if ($x>=500 && $x<1000){
      echo 2;
    }else if ($x<2500){  /*will be >1000 if you have checked for <500 before*/
      echo 3;
    }.....`

Answer (score 1):

It appears it's not the value you're expecting (int value of 670).

1. **Less than** or equal to 100? Yes: echo 1. This tells you that indeed the value is **not an int value of 670**.
2. The rest fail their boolean tests, as they don't pass those conditions.

To troubleshoot, try:

```
echo $x;
```

Perhaps explicitly cast that value as/after it comes out of your call to MySQL:

```
$x = (int)$x;
```

Comment: x as 670 should return a 2.  670 is not less than 100

Comment: @user: you got the gist of what I was saying then. $x does not have an int value of 670 then. You've proven that with your hardcoded int value of 670. Suspect your db call is returning a string or other.

Comment: but when i echo it out, it does.  i tried trim() also and that didnt work.

Answer (score -1):

If this is indeed php, you $x surely is not 670.

[See example here](http://codepad.org/JGnsyWO6)

Coudl you provide the code where you read x from the DB?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    $x = $x + 0.0;

     if ($x<=100){
     echo 1;
     }

     if ($x>=500 && $x<1000){
     echo 2;
     }

     if ($x>=1000 && $x<2500){
     echo 3;
     }

     if ($x>=2500 && $x<5000){
     echo 4;
      }

     if ($x>=5000 && $x<7500){
     echo 5;
     }

     if ($x>=7500  && $x<100000){
      echo 6;
     }

     if ($x>=10000){
     echo 7;
     }
```